# Lebesgue measure is separable?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I would like to better understand the following definition:

$(M, \mathcal {A}, \mu) $ a probability space is **separable** if there exists a countable family $ \mathcal {E} \subset \mathcal {A} $ such that for all $ A \in \mathcal{A} $ and $ \varepsilon> $ 0, there is $ B \in \mathcal {E} $ such that $ \mu (A \triangle B )<\varepsilon$.

I wonder if the Lebesgue probability space ($M=[0,1],$ $\mathcal {A}=$Lebesgue measurable sets in [0,1], $\mu=m$) is separable, as finding  $\mathcal {E} $?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Perhaps, such that $\mu(A\triangle B)<\varepsilon$?

Comment: Note that Lebesgue measure is regular (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure). So you may try with $\cal{E}= \{(a_i, b_i)\}$ where $a_i, b_i $ are the rational numbers in $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ (did not check, though)

Comment: @Thomas: what about $A = [0,\frac13] \cup [\frac23,1]$?

Comment: @user133281 Sorry my fault. But you can take countable unions of these sets. (as I mentioned, I did not check this)